# Web development code editor for Mac

Tags: osx, web-development, text-editor, git, ftp

I'm looking for a code editor for Mac. Free or purchased, doesn't matter.

The requirements are:

- *Instant* autocomplete/autosuggest for HTML, CSS, JS, PHP (i.e. suggestions displayed immediately after every keystroke, but the option to turn it off, display suggestions only with hotkey, or add delay)
- Highlight blocks (either like [this](http://www.techsupportalert.com/files/images/Notepadpp.gif) or [this](http://www.codeguru.com/images/article/17385/Figure%202%20-%20Gray%20Highlight.png)), where it is easy and obvious to see where a block starts and ends
- Ability to FTP to server directly
- HotKeys for: FTP to server, refresh and load in local browser, cursor placement (i.e. Adobe DW has Command+Shift+u for FTP, and Command+r for refresh in local browser, and *most* editors have Command+Left/Right to move cursor to start/end of line)
- Ability to push and commit to Git repo directly

I normally use Adobe DW CS6. Adobe DW does most of this pretty well, and I particularly enjoy the CSS dialogue box, which helps speed up CSS styling. But their code hinting sucks, and do not offer block highlighting of any kind. You also cannot push/commit to Git repo from within the software, which is a massive pain.

Adobe DW also has lacklustre commenting hotkey functionality, and command+arrow works poorly for navigating (i.e. the best you can set for command+left is to push the cursor to the very left of the line, next to the gutter with the line numbers, rather than just to the start of the text on that line).

Like I said, I normally use Adobe DW CS6, but it is glitchy as hell, and randomly crashes every now and then. Also quite heavy on resources, and eventually bogs my system down enough to the point of needing to restart the comp, especially if running other heavy processes. Maybe the new cloud-based version is better?

Ideally, something that has low overhead, has simple Git setup. I don't need WYSIWYG, and honestly would probably prefer not. Something without too much screen real estate. Moving between windows is a pain, if the editor takes up the entire screen. Small bezel around window, and collapsable menus would be ideal.

I reckon I've over-constrained the requirements, have my doubts that such a wonderful piece of kit exists.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/). Based on your requirements it has:

- Instant autocomplete/autosuggest for HTML, CSS, and JS. I am not sure about PHP, but you try PHPStorm for that.
- Highlight blocks (either like this or this), where it is easy and obvious to see where a block starts and ends.
- Ability to push and commit to Git repo directly.

I am not sure abot FTP capabilities, but I personally use FileZilla(https://filezilla-project.org/) for FTP connections. It si great.

Comment: WebStorm is made by the same company (JetBrains) as the IntelliJ product mentioned in the other Answer. They have a very powerful IDE engine that underlies their various products.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [IntelliJ IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). It supports all JVM languages, HTML5, Javascript, TypeScript, Java EE, Spring, GWT, Vaadin, Play, Grails, Other Frameworks, Git, SVN, Mercurial, CVS.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) from Microsoft. Why?

- Built in git support
- Intellisense for most languages (through extensions)
- Loads of other extensions
- Cross-platform (if you use multiple platforms)

I use Code. I don't know if there is an extension for FTP, though.